# Number of significant canonical correlations as "complexity measure" (CCA)

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, canonical-correlation

I want to study the association between 3 sets of variables A, B, C with about 15 variables each. For that i use canonical correlation analysis.

Now i have 4 significant canonical correlation coefficients between the projections of A and B but only 1 between the projections of A and C.

My questions are now:

1) Is the strength of the association of the two sets in any way reflected in the number of significant canonical correlation coefficients?

2) It appears appealing to say, that the association between A and B is more complex than between A and C. Would you agree?

I'm sure i'm not the first one to come up with those thoughts but couldn't find anything on those specific issues. Any comment, help, literature advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: Classic CCA is 2-set CCA. Generalized CCA is for any number of sets; it, however, projects not on "the other" set but on the "averaged" set. Regarding your questions now. (1) The strength of association between sets is not necessarily reflected by the _number of_ strong/significant can. correlations. This number is the essential dimensionality size, necessary to account for the association. (2) More "complex"? Well, maybe it is a word to choose. Dimensionality is complexity, in a sense.

Comment: thanks!so if i'm interested in the association of A and B and A and C but not B and C, it would still be necessary to perform GCCA instead of CCA? Logically, B and C are not related.

Comment: any thoughts? Iwant to add another question.
Assume i have a correlation coefficient of 0.5 between sets A and B and 0.8 between A and C. Would you agree to the conclusion that A and B seem to have a higher (linear) association than A and C like when interpreting standard correlation coefficients. Or is this not true due to the number of possible canonical correlation coefficients and possible?

Comment: `so if i'm interested in the association...perform GCCA instead` No, I don't see reasons to perform GCCA in your case. `Would you agree to the conclusion that A and B seem...` I would say "The 1st (strongest) dimension of linear association between A and C is correlation 0.8. The 1st (strongest) dimension of linear association between A and B is correlation 0.5."

Comment: If you want to see to what extent the two these "strongest dimensions" coincide you should save values of canonical variates and observe their correlations. Can. corr 0.8 is the Pearson correlation between "AvsC variate 1 from A" and "AvsC variate 1 from C". Can. corr 0.5 is the Pearson correlation between "AvsB variate 1 from A" and "AvsB variate 1 from B". See how much "AvsC variate 1 from A" and "AvsB variate 1 from A" correlate.